# Error while installing Cloudera Hue on MAC OS 13.0.1

Tags: python, cloudera, hue

Error while executing make file

I currently have python3.9 and python2.7 also

```
hue (master)> make                                                                       (base) 
"PYTHON_VER is python2.7."
"Python 2 module install of desktop/ext-py"
/Users/timberman/hue/Makefile.vars:67: *** "Error: must have python development packages for python2.7. Could not find Python.h. Please install python2.7-devel or python2.7-dev".  Stop.
```

Tried switching between python enviorments using pyenv

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile only checks Python2.7 (which is end of life, so do not use it) or Python 3.8.

So uninstall 2.7 (if you can), install 3.8, and try again. You may need to run

`PYTHON_VER=python3.8 distclean make`

Besides this, macOS may not be a supported build environment.
As the errors say its looking for UNIX packages.

Or, install Docker and run the HUE container